# Function Calling Itself, Can't Dodge StackOverflow Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception, stack-overflow

I understand that this is bad programming practice and redundant coding but I am curios.

I am simply counting a number up to 9999999 in a while loop. The `Add()` function simply increases that number and prints it out.

Inside the `Add()` Function I call the `Add()` function.

My program successfully prints out 12000ish numbers before I get a StackOverflow Exception.

So my question = Is there any way to ignore this error and keep counting?

I have tried `On Error Resume`, `Try/Catch`, and `throw`

My code is as follows.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    While number1 < 9999999
        Try
            add()
        Catch ex As StackOverflowException
            ''Do Stuff here
        End Try
    End While
End Sub


  Function add()
    number1 = number1 + 1
    Trace.WriteLine(number1) ''Error is throw here
    add()
    Return number1
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you calling `add()` from `add()`?  Let the `While` loop take care of it.

Comment: @mellamokb I know its bad programming practice, i am curious as to if theres a way to handle this exception without crashing

Comment: That's like asking how to blow your own brains out without dying. (The answer: miss.)

Comment: Your while loop does nothing, if you leave it out and just call add() at that point it would do just the same thing as it does now, and it wont ever stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since VB.NET does not support [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), there is no way you can make an infinite recursion without eventually overflowing the stack.

Comment: Technically it's not infinite (it stops at 9999999) :-).  Can the stack size be increased in .NET?

Comment: @mellamokb: The very first call to `add()` inside the `Try...Catch` never returns, so the `While ...` has no effect.

Comment: `function oop() { oop(); return "Oops, my bad, you are correct!"; }`

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to ignore this error

No. The only thing you can do is avoid causing it in the first place.  Most of the time, StackOverflowExceptions are uncatchable. From [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default.

Answer (score 1):

You never return from the function:

```
Function add()
    number1 = number1 + 1
    Trace.WriteLine(number1)
    add()
    Return number1
End Function
```

So, `add` calls `add` calls `add` - at some point you are blowing the stack. You need some sort of exit condition to test for.

For example:

```
Function add()
    number1 = number1 + 1
    Trace.WriteLine(number1)

    If number1 < 99999999 Then
      add()
    Else
      Return number1
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method from this:

```
Function add()     
    number1 = number1 + 1     
    Trace.WriteLine(number1) ''Error is throw here     
    add()     
    Return number1 
End Function
```

To this:

```
Function add()     
    number1 = number1 + 1     
    Trace.WriteLine(number1) ''Error is throw here     
    Return number1 
End Function
```

Keep the rest of your code the same and the stack overflow will not happen.